# I need to show which users are online for my AJAX Chat

Tags: php, ajax, json, chat

I have an inline chat application which I got from [Ajax Chat](http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/), which is working brilliantly. The application allows a user to chat with users that are registered on the system. Ie: [image: Here is a list of the users]

Now I need to show if the user is online or offline.

So my question is how do I show online users using PHP?

Thank You

Comment: I have a users table that captures if the user is logged in, I tryed checking that table if the user is logged in. But that ddnt work well because the user always forget to logout, so it will show that he is online evrytime

Comment: I tot mayb their is a function that shows who's online on my application.

Comment: Gotcha, read my awnser. What you have to do is timestamp the activity. If there is not activity for like 5 or 10 minutes, activate a script to let the user log out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need is a way to register users activity.

One way you can do this is doing it by sessions within PHP, and you log these. There are tons of ways to register then your activity in a log. If the activity is not updated for example in 5 minutes, the user is offline. Bassically you just need then a sessionId, and a timestamp (and i would recommend this also to hang to a userid). If offline, there is no userId assigned and when online you add a userId. If you have those, its pretty easy. Its a matter of updating them constantly when a new page is loaded and if they log out, you simply destroy the session, or update it so it wont be linked to the user.

It may not be the best system, but it works, and it might help you.

Comment: Thanks, let me analyse your solution and i'll get back to you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your specific needs. Pardon me, If I am wrong.

If Jabber support is there with Ajax Chat, why not try ejabberd kind of XMPP servers rather than re-inventing the wheels on your own. And you could have a look at Apache Vysper too, since it has support of extension modules too. If XMPP server is there, users presence handling and message transfer would become a cake walk.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a constantly update for a table in your database that save the last change in an user and save the date time... so if that date is more than 5 or 10 min, the user ir off..you can do it with ajax...

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is have a script that the clients run to do an ajax call to update a entry in your database with a time stamp for last seen. Not too often or you will overload your server.

you can also put some if statements where it checks for keystrokes, mouse movement, and if the window is active if you really want to get technical and do a away status.

then in active chats just check the time stamp for active messages or when the user list is open. anything outside a acceptable range will show the user as off line. 5 minutes seems pretty long to me. poll for a check every 10 seconds maybe?